# iptables: forward requests to different local port with masquerading

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, nat

I run a web app on port 80 that for some APIs requires whitelisting of source IPs.
Because anyone from within my /19 network should be able to use these APIs and because this web app doesn't support the CIDR notation for whitelisting, I am thinking about the following setup:

- have anyone from my /19 network connect to my server on port 1337.
- on the linux Webserver, reroute traffic from port 1337 to port 80, using masquerading
- in my web app, whitelist IP 127.0.0.1 only, since to the web app, all traffic comes from localhost
- ensure that responses from my API make it back to the source

How would the iptable rule(s) look like for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding from a standard NIC (`eth0`) to a loopback interface (`lo`) is disabled by default.
Remove any previous (broken) iptables rules and execute the following:

```
# Forward any traffic destined to TCP 1337 on eth0 to 80 on loopback if source network is X.X.X.X/19
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -s X.X.X.X/19 --dport 1337 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
# Then allow forwarding from standard NIC to loopback (assuming eth0 is the standard NIC)
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```